# Making an image follow only a portion of a CGPath

Tags: iphone, core-animation, core-graphics, mapkit, cakeyframeanimation

I realize it's not very difficult to make an image follow a pre-determined path on iPhone (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559285/making-an-image-follow-a-pre-defined-path-in-iphone)), but I'm wondering if it's possible for the image to only follow *part* of the path. For example, if I have a path that goes from A to B, how do I get the image to only animate 1/4 the way towards B? I drew a diagram below.

One method I've considered is drawing a new transparent path over the old one that's only 1/4 as long. But if there's no point 1/4 down the path, this isn't really possible. Any other ideas?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.

With CAShapeLayer, it has strokeStart and strokeEnd properties that determines where along the shape to start drawing and where to end. If you used start strokeStart and strokeEnd of .5, you'd get an infinitely small part of the middle of the path, for example. (In practice, you'd probably have to use .49 to .51 or something to actually get it to draw).

I don't see any facility for making a CAKeyframeAnimation only run for part of it's path however.

I would suggest posting this to the Core Animation forum on Apple's site. There are several Apple engineers that post their fairly regularly, and they know their stuff.